# What could cause my windows 7 laptop to repeatedly lose wifi connection?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

For about 2 weeks now my laptop keeps dropping off the wifi. I reinstalled Windows a few weeks ago but this issue didn't start immediately after the reinstall.

- Windows is up to date, drivers for both adapters are up to date.
- The problem happens on both the internal (Atheros AR9002WB-1NG, connecting to 2.4GHz) and USB (Netgear A6100, connecting to 5GHz) NIC, so I suspect it's neither device or driver. It would be too much of a coincidence for both to fail at the same time.
- While the laptop reports no available networks various other devices, including Netflix or Youtube on Chromecast. This, and the fact that both the 2.4 and 5GHz networks are affected makes me believe it's unlikely that the router is the culprit.
- When the connection goes it first loses the network it's connected to, a few seconds later it says no networks are available.
- Sometimes the Windows diagnose/ troubleshoot fixes the issue with a restart of the adapter, sometimes that doesn't work. Sometimes moving the USB wifi adapter to another USB port fixes the issue.
- After reading various forums I have already taken the following actions:
- Disabled Power Management on both adapters
- Disabled Client for Microsoft Networks
- Disabled IPv6
- Disabled Netbios
- Set fixed DNS servers

There are now no more errors in Event Viewer, other than Event ID 1014, no response from DNS, which I'm pretty sure is a symptom, not a cause.

I'm out of options at this point. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried troubleshooting or replacing the actual router? Are other devices losing connectivity too? If both adapters are failing at the same time, it seems probable that the router is the root cause of the problem.

Comment: To diagnose whether it's OS-related or hardware-related (e.g. an electrical noise source, as well as in the PC itself), make a live USB stick (such as Ubuntu) and run from the USB drive, without installation. If there is no dropout, then it's Windows OS, a failing HDD or driver/software problems causing the issue.

Comment: Is this issue repeatable at a hotspot, i.e Starbucks or a cafe etc?